# Do I need a new MobileServiceClient for every screen in Azure SQL driven Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

How does one implement global data in a Xamarin.Forms app?  I don't want to create a MobileServiceClient instance objects for each screen, would prefer a singleton.  For that matter, what is the best way to keep any global data, like user information, across an entire Xamarin.Forms (PCL) app or from screen to screen?

Comment: if you want to use a Singleton, then create one.  There is nothing preventing you from doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like @Jason said, you can do this anywhere you want. I personally use the `App.xaml.cs`/`App.cs` class for this but it is best to be very selective about it so you do not have an enormous `App` class that becomes unwieldy.

Some Azure Notification Hub guides from Microsoft simply put a singleton within the class file that the singleton is a part of so you could also do that.

Comment: Here's how it's done in the Xamarin.Forms quickstart, which was reviewed by Xamarin engineers: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/blob/master/client/xamarin.forms/ZUMOAPPNAME/TodoItemManager.cs#L26

Comment: Another fine way to do it